# Openshift origin console don't display pods

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Seems openshift console has problem showing the pod created by DeploymentConfig, after labeling the pod.

My Use Case:

I have two ldap server, one as master service, and another as slave service(much like mysql master, slave), but these two service will serve only as internal service, just for replication between them(as pod ip is not accessible from each other).

And I plan to exposed another service(e.g. ldap-outer-service) service, for outer usage, which will include pods in master and slave service.

Deploy Steps:

After master service is ready, I deploy the slave service. This slave service will be replicated with master service. Only after the replication is successfully setup and data is initialized with master service, the POD in slave service should be added to outer service

Issue:

After slave service is ready, I label the pod in the slave service, to be the same as outer service, then "oc describe service ldap-outer-service" shows endpoint is there, but the openshift console just doesn't show the pod.

Comment: Matching of service with pods created by the deployment configuration is dictated by the selector under the service specification. This is different to the labels in the metadata of the service. BTW, not sure why you would want to go about it in the order you are. Usually you would use 'oc new-app' and it would do everything for you. If wanted to do it step by step, you would use 'oc create deploymentconfig' and then 'oc expose deploymentconfig'. What are the actual commands you are running?

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton. I updated my use cases and issue details above

Comment: Where in the web console are you expecting to see it? What were the actual ``oc`` commands you used to do each step?

Comment: In each step:
1. oc new-app --file=master.yaml
    this template define two service: master ldap service and outer-ldap-service, also DeploymentConfig.
2. oc new-app --file=slave.yaml
    this template define one service slave ldap service, and also DeploymentConfig.
3. when deployment finishes in slave template, means the pod (trigger by the slave template)is ready, I execute following:
    oc label pod pod-name-created-by-slave-template name=ldap-outer-service
4. Then I expect that this pod can show in the ldap-outer-service.

Comment: Also  I tried simple case and it works: 

create one service and one pod(without dc, rc, just plain pod). label this pod same as service, then openshift's console can watch this change and update the service view, to contains the pod immediately.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, right now, I tried another way, with petset. But still I believe this is a console bug.

Comment: It is too hard to tell from what information you have given as can't easilt reproduce it. Suggest you subscribe to OpenShift list at https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo/users and ask in there.